# How does xenon react with O₂F₂?

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, redox, halides, noble-gases

This reaction was asked in my college entrance exam. I searched through the entire Internet, but I couldn't find any papers/sources.

I suspect since O₂F₂ is a strong fluorinating agent, one of the xenon fluorides (XeF₂, XeF₄, or XeF6) will form, but I am not sure. Reaction conditions were not given in the question.

Comment: This was asked in JEE advance this year (right ?). I gave it too btw.

Comment: $$\ce{XeF4 + O2F2 ->[143K] XeF6 + O2}$$ source:- https://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/lech107.pdf page 40 in the pdf

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From my research, it really depends on the experimental conditions and procedure. One paper in 1965 found that primarily $\ce{XeF2}$ was formed when xenon reacted with $\ce{O2F2}$ at low temperatures$^1$. In contrast, another paper found a mixture of $\ce{XeF2}$ and $\ce{XeF4}$ was formed, and prolonged exposure to $\ce{O2F2}$ generated mostly $\ce{XeF4}$ but no $\ce{XeF6}$ was observed$^2$.

**Sources:**

1. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ic50027a038
2. https://pubs.acs.org/doi/10.1021/ic00334a037

Comment: How does a Xenon fluorine bond work exactly? I thought Xenon is a noble gas so it wouldn't react

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal, Xenon is the least-noble of the non-radioactive noble gasses, and fluorine is extremely reactive.  This lets the fluorine bond to the outer-shell electrons of xenon.

Comment: @SidharthGhoshal This should answer your question: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/31845/why-are-there-more-fluoride-compounds-formed-with-xenon